# PHP How do I perform these checks faster/or load the page faster?

Tags: php, performance, api

I'm new to PHP and I am wondering what is either a better way to perform this operation? The PHP uses 2 API's provided by own3d.tv and justin.tv to check a stream's status whether it's online/offline. The way I implemented it is horrible, since if you load the page, it checks each and every stream within the PHP individually and then only displays the page and the results. My question is, how can I load the page either a) quicker or b) using jquery or something to display the page first, but by each stream it would say "Loading..." and when it's actually checked it, display the result like it is below.

Here's **all** the PHP in mention.

```
<html>
<body>
<title>Streams</title>

<?php

function  pageTime()
{
static $_pt;
    if($_pt == 0) $_pt = microtime(true);
    else return (string)(round(microtime(true)-$_pt ,3));
}

pageTime();

//justin.tv
echo '<b>Justin.tv: </b> <br>';

//eg.demon
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=dotademon", 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_dotademon') {
echo 'EG.Demon <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($json_array[0]['channel_count']); echo ' - <a href="http://www.justin.tv/dotademon/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'EG.Demon <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//mouz.trixi
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=trixilulz", 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_trixilulz') {
echo 'Mouz.Trixi - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($json_array[0]['channel_count']); echo ' - <a href="http://www.justin.tv/trixilulz/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'Mouz.Trixi - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//teamdignitascomewithme
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=leceweme", 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_leceweme') {
echo 'Dignitas.ComeWithMe - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($json_array[0]['channel_count']); echo ' - <a href="http://www.justin.tv/leceweme/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'Dignitas.ComeWithMe - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//thepremierleague
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=thepremierleague", 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_thepremierleague') {
echo 'The Premier League - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($json_array[0]['channel_count']); echo ' - <a href="http://www.justin.tv/thepremierleague/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'The Premier League - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//own3d.tv
echo ' <br>';
echo '<b>Own3d.tv: </b> <br>';

//joindota with tobi wan
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=10588");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'joinDOTA with Tobi Wan <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/10588/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'joinDOTA with Tobi Wan <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//navidendi
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=106735");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Na`Vi.Dendi <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/106735/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'Na`Vi.Dendi <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//ddlink
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=117967");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'DD.Link <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/117967">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'SK.Link <sup><b>Popular</b></sup> - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}   

//gosugamers
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=155074");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'GosuGamers - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/155074/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'GosuGamers - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//mtwsynderen
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=179879");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'mTw.Synderen - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/179879">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'mTw.Synderen - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}

//gosugamers with purge
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=155073");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'GosuGamers with Purge - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/155073">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'GosuGamers with Purge - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}       

//dotaoommentarieswithluminous
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=160379");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'DotA Commentaries with Luminous - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/160379">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'DotA Commentaries with Luminous - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}   

//teamdignitascomewithme
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=40553");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Dignitas.ComeWithMe - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/40553">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'Dignitas.ComeWithMe - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}   

//loda
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=73096");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Loda - <font color="green"><b>Online</b></font> - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/73096">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo 'Loda - <font color="red"><b>Offline</b></font> <br>';
}   
echo ' <br/>';
echo "The statuses were primitively checked in ". pageTime()." seconds.";   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: you need more explanation if you want help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an absolute most basic example, using AJAX and jQuery

jQuery on the main page:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#stream1").load("stream1.php"); 
   $("#stream2").load("stream2.php"); 
   ...
});
```

HTML on main page:

```
<div id="stream1">Loading...</div>
<div id="stream2">Loading...</div>
...
```

Where `stream1.php`, `stream2.php` are files using the code you posted for each individual stream.

Consider using the $.ajax method in jQuery and playing around with ways to make it more functional.  Should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, this works perfectly and can definitely work on top of this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using jQuery's [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This method has a callback called success, which is where you would replace the "Loading..." to "Online" or "Offline" depending on the result.

Answer (score 0):

To make this even faster I would suggest keeping your script how it is and running a cronjob every 5 mins or so, and save the online offline users in a local database. This will be the fastest possible way because query a local database is way faster than relying on a third party site to respond.